# How to insert only date or day or year from date or datetime data type?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to insert only date or day or year from `date` or `datetime` data type?

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: What language are you using as a client?

Comment: what SQL are you using ? it may differ between MSSQL/MySql/Oracle

Answer (score 0):

You must have properly defined type on column into which you are inserting. If you are trying to insert only the datepart, it should work correctly (with time part being set to zeros or if the column type is `Date`), but if you only have day or year, be aware that their type is `Integer`, not `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

The return type will be integer:

```
    SELECT DATEPART(DD,GETDATE()) 'Day', GETDATE() 

    SELECT DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()) 'Month', GETDATE() 

    SELECT DATEPART(YY,GETDATE()) 'Year', GETDATE()
```